# How to return an array in a c++ function

Tags: c++, arrays

```cpp
int main()
{    
    std::string my_string= "16657";
    std::map<std::string, std::array<std::string, 2>> m_msg_int;
    std::array<std::string, 2> arrId;
    arrId[0] = "ABC";
    arrId[1] = "XYZ/CDE";
    m_msg_int[my_string] = arrId;
    get_msg_type(const std::string& msg_type);
}

const string get_msg_type(const std::string& msg_type)
{
    TRC_ENTER(get_interface_and_msg_type, "")
    std::map<std::string, std::array<std::string, 2>>::const_iterator it = m_msg_int.find(msg_type);
    std::array<std::string, 2> intfMsg;
    if (m_msg_int.end() != it)
    {
        intfMsg = it->second;
    }

    return intfMsg;
}
```

I'm confused about how to return this array and extract the values.
Maybe the return type is not correct?

> initializing argument 1 of ‘std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&&, const _Tp&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>;

Comment: [Edit] the question to include a [mre] and include the full error message and where in the code it occurs.

Comment: The code shown cannot possibly produce the error message you cite, as it doesn't use `ostream` or `operator<<`. The code you actually compile must needs differ from the code you show.

Comment: Variable intfMsg is array. But your return type of function is const string. Is it right?

Comment: `m_msg_int` is local to `main()`. `get_msg_type()` can't access it. You need to either move `m_msg_int` into global scope, or else pass it into `get_msg_type()` as a parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take help of below code that could be help you to solve your problem

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
using namespace std;

array<int, 4> myFuntion(){
    array<int, 4> arr = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    cout << arr[3] << endl;

    return arr;
}

int main()
{
    array<int, 4> out = myFuntion();

    cout << "output" << out[2] << endl;
    return 0;
}
```